# Powershell, shortcut to UPnP device

Tags: windows, powershell, upnp

I'm trying to create powershell script that creates a desktop shortcut to an UPnP device. I have successfully used $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut() to create a shortcut to an .exe file or a http address, but I don't understand how to specify the address of a device. However, I can create a shortcut manually by right clicking the devices in Windows Explorer, but how do I do the same programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Creation of Custom Shortcut with PS:

```
# Quick shortcut creation script

# This if the variable that will hold the computer name of your target device
$computer = "The Computer Name" 
# This command will create the shortcut object
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
# This is where the shortcut will be created
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("\\$computer\C$\Users\Public\Desktop\SuperAwesomeness.lnk")
# This is the program the shortcut will open
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
# This is the icon location that the shortcut will use
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\AwesomeIcon.ico,0"
# This is any extra parameters that the shortcut may have. For example, opening to a google.com when internet explorer opens
$Shortcut.Arguments = "google.com"
# This command will save all the modifications to the newly created shortcut.
$Shortcut.Save()
```

**Alternate Example** for removing USB:

```
$AppLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe"
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\USB Hardware.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $AppLocation
$Shortcut.Arguments ="shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "hotplug.dll,0"
$Shortcut.Description ="Device Removal"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory ="C:\Windows\System32"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Here is the link for reference : [Custom Shortcut with PS](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2721-create-custom-shortcut-with-powershell)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I already know how to create a simple shortcut to a file or webpage. My main problem is to specify the path to a network device. In my case I want a shortcut to a webcam. The camera is discovered in Windows and listed under network/other devices/cameraname. It's using UPnP to identify itself as uuid:Upnp-BasicDevice-1_0-<MAC>.